# What is the default size of datagram queue length in Unix Domain Sockets (AF_UNIX)? Is it configurable?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, linux-kernel, datagram

I know the maximum length of a datagram queue length can be found using 
"cat /proc/sys/net/unix/max_dgram_qlen".

I wanted to know how to find the default value that is set on boot up (like in case of the /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default for the send buffer size).

Is it possible to increase the value of max_dgram_qlen? What is the upper limit of the same?

My kernel version is 2.6.27.7. I'm new to Unix Domain Socket programming (AF_UNIX).

Thanks in advance for any comments / solutions!

Answer (score 8):

The previous answers/comments failed to understand that the OP was talking about maximum queue length in **datagrams** (max_dram_qlen) and not in **bytes**. The OS provides settings for both sizes.

You can set `max_dgram_qlen` using the following command:

```
sysctl net.unix.max_dgram_qlen=128
```

You may need to run with `sudo` and you may also need to put double quotes around `max_dgram_qlen=128` depending on your shell.

Also, see [What's the practical limit on the size of single packet transmitted over domain socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856517/whats-the-practical-limit-on-the-size-of-single-packet-transmitted-over-domain).

Answer (score 1):

man unix(7):

> The SO_SNDBUF socket option does have an effect for UNIX domain sockets, but the SO_RCVBUF option does not. For datagram sockets, the SO_SNDBUF value imposes an upper limit on the size of outgoing datagrams. This limit is calculated as the doubled (see socket(7)) option value less 32 bytes used for overhead.

Comment: Thanks Maxim for your reply. I agree the SO_SNDBUF dictates the upper limit of the size of outgoing datagrams. But, i wanted to know the default value of the queue in which first all the outgoing datagrams are queued up.

Comment: @user3184348 It's in your question, /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default

Comment: @user3184348 You can find the socket buffer size programatically using `getsockopt()`.