# What's the practical limit on the size of single packet transmitted over domain socket?

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, posix, ipc

Let us assume that there is a Unix domain socket created for a typical server-client program. The client sends a 10GB buffer over the socket and it is consumed by the server in the meanwhile.

Does OS (Linux/BSD) split the 10GB buffer into many packets and send/consume them, or are they sent at once?

If it is not possible to send 10GB buffer of domain socket in one go, then what is the practical size limit of a single packet?

Constraints:

- The program will run on both Linux 2.6.32+ and FreeBSD 9+
- Size of the buffer to be sent ranges from 3 bytes to 10GB maximum.

Comment: There is nothing 'typical' about a client that sends a 10GB buffer in one go. Typically it will read some source into a buffer measured in KB, not GB, and send it piece by piece.

Comment: @EJP Do you know how much exactly I have to break up the 10GB buffer? Every 1GB/1MB?

Comment: Howard, what is the type of your socket? How it was created and how do you send|recv data?

Comment: It looks like it's answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729315/what-is-the-max-size-of-af-unix-datagram-message-that-can-be-sent-in-linux

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are a number of factors which will determine the maximum of size of a packet that can be sent on a Unix socket:

1. The `wmem_max` socket send buffer maximum size kernel setting, which determines the maximum size of the send buffer that can be set using `setsockopt (SO_SNDBUF)`. The current setting can be read from `/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max` and can be set using `sysctl net.core.wmem_max=VALUE` (add the setting to `/etc/sysctl.conf` to make the change persistent across reboots). Note this setting applies to all sockets and socket protocols, not just to Unix sockets.
2. If multiple packets are sent to a Unix socket (using SOCK_DATAGRAM), then the maximum amount of data which can be sent without blocking depends on both the size of the socket send buffer (see above) *and* the maximum number of unread packets on the Unix socket (kernel parameter `net.unix.max_dgram_qlen`).
3. Finally, a packet (SOCK_DATAGRAM) requires contiguous memory (as per [What is the max size of AF_UNIX datagram message that can be sent in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729315)). How much contiguous memory is available in the kernel will depend on many factors (e.g. the I/O load on the system, etc...).

So to maximize the performance on your application, you need a large socket buffer size (to minimize the user/kernel space context switches due to socket write system calls) and a large Unix socket queue (to decouple the producer and consumer as much as possible). However, the product of the socket send buffer size and queue length must not be so large as to cause the kernel to run out of contiguous memory areas (causing write failures).

The actual figures will depend on your system configuration and usage. You will need to determine the limits by testing... start say with `wmem_max` at 256Kb and `max_dgram_qlen` at 32 and keep doubling `wmem_max` until you notice things start breaking. You will need to adjust `max_dgram_qlen` to balance the activity of the producer and consumer to a certain extent (although if the producer is much faster or much slower than the consumer, the queue size won't have much affect).

Note your producer will have to specifically setup the socket send buffer size to `wmem_max` bytes with a call to `setsockopt (SO_SNDBUF)` and will have to split data into `wmem_max` byte chunks (and the consumer will have to reassemble them).

Best guess: the practical limits will be around wmem_max ~8Mb and unix_dgram_qlen ~32.

Comment: You are correct. By breaking the buffer into 128KB pieces, I have successfully transferred over 1GB of buffered data over domain socket. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

There are no "packets" per se with domain sockets.  The semantics of tcp "streams" or udp "datagrams" are sort of simulated w/i the kernel to look similar to user space apps but that's about as far as it goes.  The mechanics aren't as involved as network sockets using network protocols.  What you are really interested in here is how much the kernel will buffer for you.

From your program's perspective it doesn't really matter.  Think of the socket as a pipe or FIFO.  When the buffer fills you are going to block; if the socket is non-blocking you are going to get short writes (assuming streams) or error with EAGAIN.  This is true regardless of the size of the buffer.  However you should be able query the buffer size with `getsockopt` and to increase its size with `setsockopt` but I doubt you are going to get anywhere near 10GB.

Alternatively, you might look at `sendfile`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid that sendfile may not be suitable for my use case - in my use case the buffer size varies greatly, range from 3 Bytes lowest to 10GB highest.

Comment: Since you're sending to another program on the same host, perhaps you'd rather just send the path to the file (if it's a file-on-disk) and let the other program read it directly; or if it's data-in-RAM, perhaps use mmap() so that the other program can read it directly from shared memory?

Comment: setsockopt  with SO_SNDBUF is limited by sysctl_wmem_max (wmem_max sysctl)

Comment: This answer is wrong. Unix domain sockets can be opened as SOCK_DGRAM, what preserve boundaries between writes, and each read corresponds to one write. Simulated or not, it is a datagram, even in name.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ideas here.  One is the size of the packet sent if using SOCK_DGRAM and the other is the size of the buffer for the domain socket. This depends on the variables set with the domain socket.  Size can depend if it is a memory file socket.

Answer (score -4):

If you're talking about SOCK_DGRAM, it is easily determined by experiment. It seems a lot more likely that you're talking about SOCK_STREAM, in which case it simply does not matter. SOCK_STREAM will sort it outer you. Just write in whatever size chunks you like: the larger the better.